# Does TLS convert individual messages to ciphertext? If the network is breached, is the data exposed?

Tags: encryption, block-cipher, tls, transport-security

As far as I understand it, TLS creates a tunnel or channel or secure connection between the parties right? Where everything is protected? But hypothetically if the network gets breached, would the raw data/message sent from one client to another through a central server be readable? If someone gets inside the tunnel somehow, would they be able to see the raw data on the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As far as I understand it, TLS creates a tunnel or channel or secure connection between the parties right? Where everything is protected?

That is correct; TLS tries to protect the data being transmitted between the TLS client and the TLS server.

> if the network gets breached, would the raw data/message sent from one client to another through a central server be readable?

Depends on how TLS is being used.  If client A creates a TLS connection to a server, and client B creates a TLS connection to the same server, and client A sends data through the TLS connection to the server, which forwards the data to B via that TLS connection, then the server can obviously see the data in the clear; if the server is successfully attacked, then the attacker could potentially see that data.

After all, all TLS does is try to protect the data as it is being transmitted; if an attacker can see the data before it gets into the TLS tunnel or after it leaves it, well, it's not TLS's problem.

On the other hand, if client A sets up a TLS connection to client B (with one of the two sides acting as a TLS server - TLS negotiation demands that one of the two sides take the server role), then any data sent through the TLS connection between A and B is secure (assuming, of course, that clients A and B are secure).

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer!